Setup ts-jest with ESM & Typescript without babel
I have a project with the following structure (base is rootDir):
src
--apps
--consumers
--containers
tests
--consumerTests

I have tried a lot of configurations but what semi-works for me now is having jest.config.ts look like this:
...
clearMocks: true,
collectCoverage: true,
coverageDirectory: "coverage",
coverageProvider: "v8",
preset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts-esm",
...

Also, allowJs is enabled in tsconfig.json
However, all imports have to be (example)
import CNConsumers from "../../src/consumers/cnConsumers";
Moreover, I get other errors which are not present during normal build with tsc (ts-jest uses ts-node).
My tsconfig.json looks like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2022"],
    "module": "es2022",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node10",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "types": ["node"],
    "outDir": "build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Currently I am having the following error because I use top-level awaits, which compile just fine with tsc:
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
Is there a clearer and better way of testing using ts-jest without babel?
I am also not against building with tsc and running tests that way, but I have not found a way to do it and from what I gathered it breaks type checking.
EDIT: It seems my error disappears by using --experimental-vm-modules, adding to the number of complications to run ts-jest, which in my opinion should work easier. (Can also change preset to default-esm)
